# android application 2.3.4 sony ericsson design?

Tags: android, testing, sony

I've tested my Android app on a lot of devices and on 2 sony ericcson's with android 2.3.4 on, but the design is completly messed up on those devices.. Every textbox is clickable and there is an border around everything.. watch the screenshots below  (left u see photo on the sony ericcson and right screenshot on other phone)

Anyone knows what the problem is? Wrong theme or something??

[image] [image]

[image] [image]

Here is the code that i use for the last image:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#003e79"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:weightSum="100" >

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="50" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/ivNavigation"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerInParent="true"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:layout_weight="50"
        android:src="@null" />

    <ProgressBar
        android:id="@+id/pbNavigation"
        style="?android:attr/progressBarStyleLarge"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:visibility="visible" />

</RelativeLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvNavText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:layout_weight="50"
    android:text="Large Text"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="20dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The link to your app in Google Play looked a lot like advertisement to me: hence I removed it from your question. If you feel that the link is indeed necessary for someone answering your question, please mention why this is so, and then put the link back in your question. Thanks.

Comment: Hmm it's not really that necessary but I think it would help if someone could test the app if they have android? I really don't get something if the app is downloaded.. it is a school project..

Comment: Whether you get paid or not is not really relevant. The link is no needed (IMO). Anyway, SO is not really meant for you to find people to test your app. People here at SO *can* help you with any code issues however. So, if you could post a small working (code) example of UI components that look strange on a certain version of Android, go ahead and edit your question to include the code. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have defined the correct theme in values, values-11 and values-14 folders.

Here is an example of my themes.xml file defining a theme named MyTheme to be used for my activity named MyActivity.

**themes.xml in values folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Light"></style>

</resources>
```

**themes.xml in values-11 folder**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="MyTheme" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light"></style>

</resources>
```

Please note the for values folder the theme's parent is Theme.Light which is available in api level lower then 11. And  for values-11 folder the theme's parent is Theme.Holo.Light which is available in api level 11.

Similarly there should a themes.xml in values-14 as well if needed.

Now in your Manifest.xml you can simply use your custom theme as

```
<activity
      android:name=".MyActivity"
      android:label="@string/app_name"
      android:theme="@style/MyTheme" >    
 </activity>
```

See the how to define themes and styles on [android developer site](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html)

Hope that helps.